# Force PhpStorm to recognize a project file

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

I have an annoying scenario in PhpStorm;

When I open a file by invoking the PhpStorm launcher with a relative file path as the only argument (`phpstorm src/ZumbaController.php`) the application will launch, but as the file is saved a prompt appears;

#### open a file from the terminal

[image: open file from terminal]

#### dreaded confirm write-file dialog

[image: confirm write-file prompt]

Opening the file by the full, absolute path does not help. Having the current working directory of the shell be the real path of the project does not help either (opening from the real project directory). Is there a way to instruct PhpStorm that this file belongs to the currently-open project?

*(I considered posting on superuser, but this is more of a programers-only problem)*

Comment: Are you sure that this file is part of the project? Considering the paths on both screenshots .. there is a symlink in use somewhere in the path. From IDE point of view this is enough to treat them as different files. Need more info...

Comment: BTW -- on Linux/Mac it's better to use `pstorm` command (a Python script AFAIK) for such stuff (such command can be created somewhere from either Tools or Help menu -- something like "Create command launcher" or among these lines...)

Comment: This particular file is not tracked by git and thus not yet part of the project. But even navigating to the 'real' path of the project and opening a tracked file produces the same "do yo want to save the file" dialog.

Comment: Can you open this file in PhpStorm by finding it in Project View (or just `Navigate | File...` (`Ctrl+Shift+N` on Windows/Linux))? Maybe file belongs to folder marked as excluded or as some Library? Sorry, no other ideas from me right now.